# "Uncaught TypeError: number[i] is undefined"

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma calculadora e no meu console só recebo o erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: number[i] is undefined.
```

O código retorna o esperado funcionando, mas este erro persiste.

Segue o código:

```
let number = document.getElementsByClassName('number')

let calAction = function(){ 
    console.log('work')
}


function getNumberLoad(number){
    for(let i = 0; i <= number.length; i++)
        number[i].addEventListener('click', calAction, false)        
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getNumberLoad(number), false)
```

Comment: Pq a TAG `brasil`?

Comment: O numero de loops no for está errado, ao usar `<=` você definiu um item a mais do limite de elementos encontrados, a contagem é a partir do 0, logo o length tem que ser menor e não menor-ou-igual. Deveria ser `for(let i = 0; i < number.length; i++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

number.length te retornará o comprimento do array `number`. Entretanto, como os índices de arrays em javascript (e na maioria das linguagens de programação) começam por 0 (zero), o último índice do array é igual ao seu comprimento menos 1. Por isso, a condição de saída do seu for deverá ser `i < number.length`.